# Error : Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime-error

[image]**EmpdetApicontoller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using MyEmployee.Models;

namespace MyEmployee.Controllers
{
public class EmpdetApiController : ApiController
{
    private EmployeeEntities db = new EmployeeEntities();

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateEmployee(UpdateEmployeeRequest model, Empdet empdet)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            db.Entry(empdet).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteEmployee(int Id)
    {
        Empdet empdet = db.Empdets.Find(Id);
        if (empdet == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.Empdets.Remove(empdet);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, empdet);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SelectEmployeeList(Empdet empdet)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        Collection<Empdet> Empdets =new Collection<Empdet>( db.Empdets.ToList());
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Empdets);
    }
     return Response;
}           
}
```

while i compile my program these are the errors i m getting on the single statement at the end program in "return response",

> 1. Error:Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
> 2. Error:Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
> 3. Error:The type or namespace name 'Response' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `return` call must be inside a function! that u hv mentioned outside `SelectEmployeeList` function! And btw, Get a good profile img of Iron man like [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3682162/vikrant?tab=profile)

Comment: Hard copy of profile Pic

Comment: When i place it inside the method it shows error: "The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: no i downloaded it from zedge a long time ago..pls help me to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

It is because your `return Response;` is in your class and not in a method. The last return is on the wrong place there. Delete the line and try to compile again.

Comment: When i place it inside the method it shows error: "The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Your have to write "return response" in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

*Here is your Original Method:*

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SelectEmployeeList(Empdet empdet)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    Collection<Empdet> Empdets =new Collection<Empdet>( db.Empdets.ToList());
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Empdets);
}
 return Response;
```

**Replace it with below Solution :** (*just copy contant & Paste in your code*)

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SelectEmployeeList(Empdet empdet)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    Collection<Empdet> Empdets =new Collection<Empdet>( db.Empdets.ToList());
    return response;
    //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Empdets);
}
```

Don't use `Response`, correct variable name is `response`!

Comment: your solution is helpful but the output is not coming.. thanks